# Angular: Using moment.format method in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date, momentjs

is there a way to use the moment.format method in HTML? I'm currently using the toLocaleDateString method to display an array of dates:

```
            <ng-template let-event>
                <div>{{event.date.toLocaleDateString('en-US')}} </div>
            </ng-template>
```

But I would like to use something like:

```
            <ng-template let-event>
                <div>{{moment(event.date).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}}</div>
            </ng-template>
```

For now I get the error: "ERROR TypeError: ctx_r11.moment is not a function" even though it's working without issues when using it in the ts file via the console.log

Comment: Maybe one possibly solution will be to create custom pipe

Comment: You should read more `DatePipe` https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

You can using

```js
getDate(dateAsString) {
    if (dateAsString) {
      return new Date(dateAsString);
    }
    return;
  }
```

```html
{{ getDate(event.date) | date: "dd.MM.yyyy" }}
```